# How can I get multiple elements from an array?

Tags: javascript

```
const studentName = [];

function AddNewMember(){
    for(var i=0; i<4 ; i++){
        var num1 = document.getElementById("vorodi").value;
        studentName.push(num1);
    }
}
```

I have an input from which I want to receive five names.
You can't do this with this code. What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: what is the input?

Comment: Show us your HTML.

Comment: `You can't do this with this code` ... why not? ... what happens?

Comment: A single output with 5 names in it or 5 outputs with a name in each one ?

Comment: `document.getElementById("vorod" + i).value;`

Comment: use `getElementByClassName()` you should give those multiple elements the same class name, i hope this helps, perhaps it would easier if you presented you html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this solution

```
let num1 = document.getElementById("vorodi");
function AddNewMember(){
        let name = num1.value;
        studentName.push(name);
        num1.value = "";
        console.log(studentName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to take value of multiple inputs in (your case it is 4)

You can try below one `"vorod"+i` concat value of `i` with static text

```js
const studentName = [];

function AddNewMember(){
alert("called")
    for(var i=0; i<4 ; i++){
        var num1 = document.getElementById("vorod"+i).value;
        studentName.push(num1);
    }
    console.log(studentName)
}
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="vorod0"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="vorod1"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="vorod2"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="vorod3"><br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Add Member" onclick="AddNewMember()">
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do but if you want to get mutiple elements from your document(assuming you are working with a html page) you can use the [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) or [getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) functions but you have to put the tag or class in your html element.

Comment: It's not usually a good idea to answer a question if you don't understand it.